# Connecting from Google colab to MS SQL server

Tags: python

I am trying to connect from google colab notebook to MS SQL server. I am using the below code.

## Assuming you have the necessary connection details

```
server = 'TL358'
database = 'TtAI'
username = 'TestAI'
password = 'Password@1234$'
driver = '' (**Not able to find what i need to mention in the driver**)

conn_str =f"DRIVER={driver}; SERVER={server}; DATABASE={database}; UID={username}; PWD={password}"
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
But still facing the issue:

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [Unix ODBC] [Driver Manager] Can't open lib '': file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Please advise.

Regards
RK
```

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to use pyodbc, your operating system must have the necessary drivers installed.

In the case of Google Colab, which uses the default runtime for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, it would be necessary to install the drivers via terminal.

To get around it, you can use the [pymssql](https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/) project, which uses the [FreeTDS driver](http://www.freetds.org/).

Below is an example using pymssql and sqlalchemy (need some adjusts and definitions).

```py
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

# String
connection_url = f'mssql+pymssql://{SERVER}/{DATABASE}'

# Results
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
print(connection_url)
print(engine.connect().closed)

sql = """
SELECT TOP (1000) IllustrationID, Diagram, ModifiedDate
FROM AdventureWorks2019.Production.Illustration
"""

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(sql), con=engine.connect())
df.head(2)
```

Another advantage of using pymssql is that it is possible to use the Windows username and password to log into an MSSQL DB, emulating *Windows Authentication*